# How do you manually attack objects or enemies in Dungeon Keeper 2?

Tags: dungeon-keeper-2

I'm feeling a bit dumb here but I can't for the life of me figure out how you manually order units to attack enemies; for example, an enemy tile or cannon (which does not belong to me).

At the moment I can only make my units attack by placing them on my own tiles as near as the enemies as possible; however, this doesn't quite cut it.

Answer (score 5):

You can lure them to the object by placing that call-to-arms-flag (or whatever it's called) there. Of course going into first-person mode and instructing some of your creatures to follow you will also work quite well. I don't know if there are any other options though.

Comment: Might be good to mention, that making creatures to follow you is done by pressing <kbd>7</kbd> and then clicking on them as if you had ranged skill selected.